# How to construct a consistent location?

Tags: rascal

A typical location is constructed as follows:

```
|URI|(offset,length,<begin_line,begin_col>,<end_line,end_col>)
```

There is a relation between *offset* and *<begin_line,begin_col>*, as *offset* is the number of characters that corresponds with *<begin_line,begin_col>*. Idem for *offset+length* and *<end_line,end_col>*.

The question is whether we can obtain *<line,col>* from a *number of characters*, and vice versa, such that we can construct consistent locations?

Answer (score 0):

The column and line information are optional. You could work with just offset and length. Both Eclipse and the IO functions that support offsets work on the offset and length fields.

I think @jurgenv might have some more details on when to add the column and line offsets.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't derive one from the other without access to the original file, which is why both offset/length and line/column information is necessarily represented in a `loc` value.

So the producer of the information usually does have access to the file or source and should be able to compute both types of information. If this is impossible, then like @davy-landman says the producer can default to using only offset/length information.

Side note: offset and length are counted in *characters*, not bytes or anything encoding specific. The same holds for lines and columns.

Side note: some editors work with offset/length indexing, others work with line/column indexing, which was the main motivation for having both types in a `loc` in the first place.

Comment: we might add a library function which takes a location with offset/length and computes the line/column information by reading through the entire file. It's a bit expensive, but still useful.

Comment: one problem with this is that you need to have a consistent idea of how many characters a tab should take up if you encounter tab characters, so it's easier to do this with files that are in an IDE (since you tend to then also have the tab settings and the IDE knows the columns) versus files that you are reading in directly from disk -- this is why we don't have column info in the PHP ASTs

Comment: Interesting remark.. what is the semantics of the tab character in a `loc` line/column notation?